# White space in IE8 and no javascript ajax postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

The site that I am updating is having an issue with IE that has me stumped.  Everything works fine in Firefox (of course).  One issue has an extra blank page on all the website's pages.  The second issue is certain pages show up blank.  On those pages, there are list sets.  Those list sets have a css class called listSet.  Each list set is populated via this javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    fillApprovalList("DutaApprovalLists");
});

var fillApprovalList = function(ajaxFunction) {
if (getParameterByName("mode").toLowerCase() == "approve") {
    var $listsToFill = $(".approvalList").find(".listSet")

     $listsToFill.each(function() {
        var $currObj = $(this);
        var statusAndId = $currObj.attr("id");

        var $table = $currObj.find(".resultList");

        fillApprovalListAjax(ajaxFunction,statusAndId,0);
    });
}
}

var fillApprovalListAjax = function(ajaxFunction, statusAndId, page){

var $currObj = $("[id='"+statusAndId+"']");
var $table = $currObj.find(".resultList");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/database/services/ApprovalList.asmx/"+ajaxFunction,
    data: "{statusAndId:'" + statusAndId + "',page:"+page+"}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $table.find("tr").remove()
        $table.parent().find("#loading").hide()
        $table.append(data.d.ResultSet);

        var $pagingDiv = $table.parent().find(".paging");
        $pagingDiv.find("a").remove()
        $pagingDiv.append(data.d.Links);    
        $pagingDiv.find("a").click(pageApprovalList);

        var $countDiv= $table.parent().find("#count");
        $countDiv.empty();
        $countDiv.append(data.d.DisplayingText);    
    }
});
```

}

Now, I can't for the life of me figure out why this isnt working.  I step through the code, javascript and server side, and everything gets returned OK.  To remove the extra page, I included this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #small_boxes {
          overflow: hidden;
          padding-bottom: -150px;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

But only if I don't have this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=xxx" />
```

If I were to modify that line to be, lets say IE=EmulateIE8, then that list page renders fine, but then I have the white space on every page.  I have tried pretty much all IE= options and none fix both.  And all my javascript includes are as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
```

Having the < / script> tag.  Its kind of like a chicken and the egg deal I have going on.